# I'm trying to install pycups on mac os using the treminal, but I'm getting "building wheel for pycups (setup.py) ... error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pycups

```
$pip install pycups
Collecting pycups
    Using cached pycups-2.0.1.tar.gz (62 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycups
    Building wheel for pycups (setup.py) ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip- 
    install-_itolwzg/pycups_229a8ad4200041038747d41d5862ab4c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip- 
    install-_itolwzg/pycups_229a8ad4200041038747d41d5862ab4c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
    '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
    '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel- 
    29ml6iuu
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_itolwzg/pycups_229a8ad4200041038747d41d5862ab4c/
    Complete output (165 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cups' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DVERSION="2.0.1" - 
    I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c cupsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupsmodule.o
    cupsmodule.c: In function 'cups_enumDests':
    cupsmodule.c:422: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cupsEnumDests'
    cupsmodule.c: In function 'cups_connectDest':
    cupsmodule.c:501: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cupsConnectDest'
    cupsmodule.c:508: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    cupsmodule.c: In function 'PyInit_cups':
    cupsmodule.c:919: error: 'HTTP_STATUS_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
    cupsmodule.c:919: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    cupsmodule.c:919: error: for each function it appears in.)
    .....
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycups
    Running setup.py clean for pycups
```

Comment: Just tried it on my version and it works ok.  `filename=pycups-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl `. Installing collected packages: pycups
Successfully installed pycups-2.0.1

Comment: @PaulBrennan Thank you for your replay it worked. The problem was the pip wasn't installed properly.